# Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml; the system cannot find the file specified even i have gived the correct dtd path

Tags: hibernate

I am getting this error-

how to resolve this-

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1542)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1476)
    at com.javatpoint.mypackage.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:14)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: C:\Users\kamlesh\workspace\empdetails\hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified) Nested exception: C:\Users\kamlesh\workspace\empdetails\hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1532)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it in the doctype? That's an URL.

Use the slash `/` and not the backslash `\` (even on Windows).

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" >
<h-c><s-f>
<!-- Database connection settings -->
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto"></property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
<property name="connection.username">system</property>
<property name="connection.password">-----</property>
<property name="dialect"> org.Hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect </property>

<mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml" /></s></h

Comment: Hi Johanna,

i have made the xml file from the dtd hb-cg-3.0.dtd from the root path only under system i hv lso chk the extraction of dtd from jar

Comment: Is `C:\Users\kamlesh\workspace\empdetails` the directory where your hibernate.cfg.xml is situated? Is there the `hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd` file? You alternatively can try to replace `hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd`with `http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd`.

Comment: and hi johanna ; i also want to know how to extract dtd in the xml from a jar? for eg hibernate.cfg.dtd present in org.hibernate package of hibernate3.jar...